# If the person who asks a question finds that it's a duplicate, should they delete it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

For example, I asked a question related to wood glue and the general consensus was that it was a duplicate question. Should I delete the post or just leave it marked as a duplicate?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

If it's your own question you may delete it if you prefer, but I would lean toward closing it as a duplicate.  This helps make it easier for people to find the answers they need even when using different searches in the future.

Comment: @Hooplehead24 Think of it this way: If you couldn't find the existing one when you asked, and the autosearch couldn't find it as you were typing it, then if you leave it you're helping others out by improving the missing search results. Even if you saw the existing one and didn't realize it was a different form of the same question when you asked you're still helping others who also may not realize that.

Comment: Duplicates are good in that they are like sign posts. Just another way to get to the right content.